# Resize buttons dynamically

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a Java frame with buttons and I have defined it using `setLayout(null)`.

When I expand the frame, the buttons adjust their position vertically but not horizontally.

Any advice on how to make it dynamic?

Comment: @rishikesh-baviskar01: I have removed some text from your title and tried to put it into the question. This makes it easier to read and understand your question. Hope you agree with my changes.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Java Layouts](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

They are responsible for placing and resizing the components within your container.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend using a LayoutManager to control how your GUI components are laid out.  The most flexible manager is probably the [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), but it may be over-kill.  Even a simple FlowLayout or BoxLayout maybe sufficient if you want to have a simple frame.

Alternatively, you can use an IDE like NetBeans to visually lay out your components (the layout is code-genned).  However, knowing how basic layouts work is very useful.